# Como separar arquivos HTML numa arquitetura MVC?

Tags: angularjs, mvc

Tenho uma aplicação que usa Angular.js, o qual comecei a usar agora e nunca entendi como aplicar o conceito de MVC num projeto.

Tenho duas páginas HTML, `veiculo.html` e `index.html`, ambas estão nomeadas com o mesmo nome de "módulo" (`angular.module`) mas usam *controllers* diferentes, tudo isso está no mesmo arquivo chamado `controller.js`.

Todas as requisições HTTP e roteamentos para outras páginas estão neste mesmo arquivo `controller.js`.

Tudo isso me parece bem porco mas como faço para separar corretamente? Para cada arquivo HTML deve haver um "módulo" e um arquivo `controller.js` diferente?

Comment: Isso com certeza pode lhe ajudar: [pergunta do stack em ingês](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17363901/2087187), [um livro online de angularjs](http://www.angularjsbook.com/angular-basics/chapters/introduction/) e se você tiver cash [um livro pago](https://www.ng-book.com/)

Comment: Olá, há algum tempo assisti algumas aulas sobre angularjs pelo youtube ministradas por Rodrigo Branas. O conteúdo é de excelente qualidade e tenho certeza que vai esclarecer suas dúvidas. Segue o Link: [https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb) Bons estudos...

Comment: você também pode fazer o seguinte curso: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-angularjs

Comment: Recomendo fortemente que leia o [Guia de Estilo AngularJS](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/i18n/pt-BR.md), este guia irá explicar a você as melhores praticas para o framework. Sobre o MVC você irá ver a forma como o John Papa trata a arquitetura.

Answer (score 2):

Recentemente quebrei muito a cabeça pra solucionar esse mesmo problema. Não diria solucionar, mas achar o melhor método de organização/estruturação para o meu fluxo de trabalho (e minha necessidade de momento).

### 1 - Estrutura do projeto

O primeiro passo que tomei foi de analisar qual a estrutura que eu precisava.

- Todo o projeto é livre para qualquer um acessar?
- Existem áreas restritas?
- Dentro da área restrita existe controle de permissão?
- Um usuário visitante pode acessar apenas uma área especifica?

Com isso você pode partir de uma estrutura básica de layout e ir incrementando ao longo do projeto. O importante é você ter em mente que, em Angular, podemos trabalhar com um projeto bem modularizado. Seja esse módulo seu, ou de terceiros, o importante é ter o controle dos arquivos.

Então além de uma área de distribuição - arquivos que serão colocados na hospedagem, por exemplo, ainda temos os arquivos de desenvolvimento, ou seja, o arquivo com o código bruto.

Com isso, podemos partir de uma estrutura simples como essa:

```
_RAIZ_
index.html
_dist //Arquivos que serão utilizados no projeto
    _view
        _noauth //views SEM autenticação de usuarios
            _home
                -home.html
                -home.min.js
            _empresa
                -empresa.html
                -empresa.min.js
            [..etc..]
        _auth //views COM autenticação de usuario
            app.html
            _financeiro
                -financeiro.html
                -fincaneiro.min.js
            _suporte
                -suporte.html
                -suporte.min.js
    _js
        _main //arquivos importantes pro app rodar
            -angular.min.js
            -angular-animate.min.js
        _vendor //arquivos de terceiros
            -ngMap.min.js
            -ngMask.min.js
        _app //arquivos comum a todo o app que você criou
            -app.min.js
    _css
    _img
    [..etc..]
_src //arquivos somente usados pelo desenvolvedor
    _app
        -app-ctrl.js
        -app-factory.js
        -app-run.js
    _view
        _noauth
            _home
                home-ctrl.js
                home-factory.js
            _empresa
                empresa-ctrl.js
                empresa-factory.js
            [..etc..]
        _auth
            _financeiro
                financ-ctrl.js
                financ-directive.js
                financ-factory.js
            _suporte
                [..etc..]
    _css
        [..etc..]
```

## 2 - Arquivos

Repare que nas pastas do `dist`, todos os arquivos já estão devidamente concatenados, compilados, etc.. Prontos para irem para o projeto. Também estão todos bem segmentados, por pastas. Por que eu utilizo deste modo? Utilizo assim, pois posso fazer uso do `lazy-load`, isso me dá 2 pontos positivos.

- Meus arquivos ficam mais leves, pois estão separados. A aplicação carrega mais rápido.
- Aumento de segurança. O arquivo só vai ser carregado se o usuário estiver autenticado, possuir permissão e acessar a página.

Imagine que você tem a view `financeiro.html`, as funções dela `financeiro.min.js` só serão carregadas quando o usuário acessar ela. Antes disso, nem existira a chamada dessa função. Outra coisa também seria o carregamento, pois ao invés de ter um arquivo `app.min.js` de 180-200kb, eu possuo 2, 4, 5, 10 ou seja lá quantos forem, arquivos de 5-10kb.

Para fazer o lazy-load, existem alguns serviços, como o [requireJs](http://requirejs.org/) ou o [oc-lazyload](https://oclazyload.readme.io/).

Já na parte de juntar os arquivos, concatenar, fazer o uglify dele, eu, particularmente, uso o [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). Mas nada impede você de usar outros serviços.

## 3 - Necessidade de toda segmentação

Não vou dizer que você deve, ou que este é o melhor caminho para fazer o seu projeto. Faça uma análise da necessidade, da complexidade e do ganho real que você vai ter usando esses processos.

De nada adianta segmentar tanto assim, se no final o seu projeto é simples, possui 4-5 views, não é necessário nem estar logado. Ou por mais que você tenha mais views, nem sempre todas elas possuem diversas funções sendo necessário você segmentar todo o projeto.

Em projetos mais simples, é perfeitamente aceitável você organizar por tipo, por exemplo:

```
_RAIZ_
index.html
_dist
    _view
        app.html
        _noauth //views SEM autenticação de usuario
            -home.html
            -empresa.html
            [..etc..]
        _auth //views COM autenticação de usuario
            -financeiro.html
            -suporte.html
            [..etc..]
    _js
        _main //arquivos importantes pro app rodar
            -angular.min.js
            -angular-animate.min.js
        _vendor //arquivos de terceiros
            -ngMap.min.js
            -ngMask.min.js
        _app //arquivos comum a todo o app que você criou
            -app.min.js
    _css
    _img
    [..etc..]

_src //arquivos de desenvolvimento
    _app
        _ctrl
            home-ctrl.js
            empresa-ctrl.js
            financeiro-ctrl.js
            [..etc..]
        _factory
            home-factory.js
            empresa-factory.js
            financeiro-factory.js
            [..etc..]
        app-run.js
        app-directive.js
    _css
        [..etc..]
```

### 4 - Módulos

Quanto aos módulos, diria que você não tem uma barreira, ou limite, ou ainda mesmo restrição de uso. Crie um novo módulo sempre que você for usar uma função que vá exigir muitos arquivos com muitas funções, onde seria muito confuso misturar aos demais.

Por exemplo, eu criei um módulo `auth` onde coordeno o login e autenticação dos usuários. Esse módulo possui 5 arquivos: ctrl, directive, factory, run e config. Cada arquivo possui em média de 5 a 10 funções. Então não seria vantagem juntá-lo aos demais arquivos, seria muito confuso.

Já uma função de cadastrar cliente, editar e excluir, só me consome 1-2 arquivos (controller e factory) com 3 funções cada. Neste caso é mais viável utilizar um módulo já existente.

Só não esqueça de referenciar e inicializar o módulo que você criou em sua aplicação. Caso contrário, não há problema em usar um único módulo para todo o app.

De novo, vai depender da complexidade do seu projeto.

### 5 - Considerações

Minhas recomendações para você determinar esse fluxo seriam:

Analise bem o seu projeto, complexidade e extensão, pense bem antes de segmentar o conteúdo, nem sempre é o melhor a se fazer.

Segmente quando:

- Pastas: Tiver mais de 7-10 arquivos;
- Ctrl, factory, etc..: Quando tiver mais de 4-5 por arquivo;
- Módulo: Crie um novo quando precisar de uma função bem elaborada. Ou que você saiba que poderá utilizar em outro projeto.

Referências de leitura:

Organização do projeto - Pergunta que eu mesmo fiz aqui no grupo e que rendeu excelentes explicações: [AngularJs - Organização de arquivos para projeto grande](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97519/angularjs-organiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-arquivos-para-projeto-grande)

Guia AngularJs: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Tenho usado esse guia para TODOS os meus projetos.

Grunt - 2 questões que fiz no SO inglês para usar o Grunt em projetos grandes:

1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804659/how-to-create-and-organise-config-and-register-grunt-tasks 
2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813073/task-not-found-using-grunt

Existem muitos outros conteúdos excelentes por ai, mas acredito que com isso você consiga uma boa orientação de como prosseguir com o planejamento do projeto.

Mas não se esqueça, faça uma boa análise antes de montar a sua estrutura. Depois de montada pode ser extremamente estressante tanto a compactação como ampliação da mesma.

Obs.: Essa não é a melhor resposta, muito menos a mais correta. É apenas o método que melhor funcionou para mim.